# How do I verify a COM object can be instantiated from under another user?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, com, azure-web-roles

I have the following setup. There's a Azure web role process (WaIISHost.exe) running elevated and there's IIS7 application pool running under a local user. The local user is being created by the elevated WaIISHost.exe when it first runs. There's also an out-proc COM object registered with DCOM.

I want to be sure that the IIS process will be able to instantiate the COM object. So I need to somehow login under the local user and try to instantiate the COM object.

My current approach is to call `LogonUser()` (requesting interactive logon) via P/Invoke, obtain a logon token, then start a new thread and from that thread call `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser()` to switch to the other user and once that is done the other thread tries to instantiate the COM object.

All great, except [the interactive logon is only for Administrators by default now](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2859054/en-us) so my approach no longer works - I get

> Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer

yet if I just skip the check the IIS later instantiates the COM object just fine.

So I need to change my validation code.

One option is to try add the required privilege (interactive logon) to the user, but that's lots of P/Invoke code plus there's a chance that at come point Microsoft changes something else and I'm disallowed to adjust privileges altogether.

Is there another way to verify that a COM object can be successfully instantiated from under another user account?

Comment: can you verify the user for whom COM object will be instantiated has the administrator right? If the interactive logon is only for administrator level users, that way you can foresee if that COM can be instantiated under that user I think..

Comment: @JP_medevice: Okay, what if Microsoft removes that privilege from administrators? I don't really care of privileges - I want to know that I can have the action performed.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a universal answer, but fine for this specific scenario. One possible solution is to implement a special URL in IIS that will accept local requests only (check for `HttpRequestBase.IsLocal`) and try to instantiate the COM object. The code that previously tried impersonation will now send an HTTP request to that URL (on the same computer).